# android project not working on the device

Tags: android, android-relativelayout, android-imageview, android-sdcard, android-drawable

I wrote a simple "hello world" program on eclipse IDE including a ImageView for which i stored my image in drawable-hdpi.
This was successfully running on my android virtual device. But when i transferred this project on my android phone and tried to run it through an android app "AIDE - the Android Java IDE" it is showing an error and therefore not building its apk:

```
aapt:invalid resourse directory name:/mnt/sdcard/AppProjects/PracticeTwo/res/drawable-xxhdpi
```

Can anyone help me out in this respect that why is this error coming and how to rectify it or there is any other way to build its apk and then i could run it on my device?

Comment: Is ur folder named drawwable? Change to drawable

Comment: sorry...it was drawable only i edited that above. i am not able to understand why this error is encountered

Comment: copy the .apk from /bin directory from your codebase, place it in your flash drive on your phone. Install & run.

Comment: yep...this worked fine. thanks. but do you have any idea why the above error is encountered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm having the same problem, the version of `aapt` packed with AIDE is probably not updated!

Until the issue will be fixed, the workaround is to simply **remove that folder** (and remember to also remove the `/bin` directory, as it might still have references to it).

Note that [the only use of the `drawable-xxhdpi` directory, right now, is providing a bigger icon for `xhdpi` tablets](https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/ePQya3KsTjW).

I'll write to the developers ASAP...

Comment: This is fixed in AIDE v1.0.6

Comment: @crafter [you beat me on time](https://plus.google.com/101304250883271700981/posts/jgfq2cTjqLy) ;)

Answer (score 1):

AIDE supports xxhdpi resources starting with version 1.0.6.